# MRF24WB0MA WiFi with 32MX4 Beginners Tutorial

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab

I'm a beginner at Microchip Programming and I want to design a robot that can connect to WiFi. I have the Cerebot 32MX4 Microcontroller (PIC32MX460F512L) and the PmodWiFi card (MRF24WB0MA). I have absolutely no idea where to start. I have tried downloading various code from the internet, including the TCP/IP Stack and other sample code, but it has errors compiling or has no effect on the robot. I picked these two products because they were relatively popular and I was expecting it to be a rather straightforward process. Could you please send me the link to a step-by-step tutorial that shows me how to set this up or some working sample code for the 32MX4. Currently I have a functional 32MX4 board connected to the WiFi card through the JB header. Sorry if I sound too stupid, but this is my first time doing a project like this and I have no idea what to do.

Thanks in advance for your help, 
Guvvy

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link will help you, if found it quite useful to understand a bit more about the code provided by the Microchip solutions. It will work better if you have a development board from Microchip. I am in the same process as you!

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52108A.pdf